# Dynamically added static methods to a Python class

Tags: python, oop, static-methods

I [found](http://code.activestate.com/recipes/81732-dynamically-added-methods-to-a-class/) really good example how to add new method to the class dynamically (transplant class):

```
def say(host, msg):
   print '%s says %s' % (host.name, msg)

def funcToMethod(func, clas, method_name=None):
   setattr(clas, method_name or func.__name__, func)

class transplant:
   def __init__(self, method, host, method_name=None):
      self.host = host
      self.method = method
      setattr(host, method_name or method.__name__, self)

   def __call__(self, *args, **kwargs):
      nargs = [self.host]
      nargs.extend(args)
      return apply(self.method, nargs, kwargs)

class Patient:
   def __init__(self, name):
      self.name = name

if __name__ == '__main__':
   jimmy = Patient('Jimmy')
   transplant(say, jimmy, 'say1')
   funcToMethod(say, jimmy, 'say2')

   jimmy.say1('Hello')
   jimmy.say2(jimmy, 'Good Bye!')
```

But I don't understand, how to modify it for adding static methods. Can someone help me?

Comment: What do you mean by "static" method?

Comment: @JoachimPileborg: the [`@staticmethod` decorator](http://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#staticmethod).

Comment: And by the way, you don't add the functions to the class, you add them to an instance of the class. If you replace `jimmy` in the calls with the actual class `Patient` then you add methods to the class.

Comment: @JoachimPileborg: for a `staticmethod` to work it *has* to be added to the class; it's a descriptor.

Answer (score 23, accepted):

All you need to do is wrap the function in a `staticmethod()` call:

```
say = staticmethod(say)
```

or apply it as a decorator to the function definition:

```
@staticmethod
def say(host, msg):
    # ...
```

which comes down to the same thing.

Just remember; the `@decorator` syntax is just syntactic sugar for writing `target = decorator(target)`, where `target` is the decorated object.

Answer (score 6):

I don't see a staticmethod here. The `say` function is expecting two arguments, and the first argument, `host`, appears to be the instance of the class.

So it seems like you are simply trying to attach a new method to a class. That can be done without funcToMethod or transplant:

```
def say(self, msg):
   print '%s says %s' % (self.name, msg)

class Patient:
   def __init__(self, name):
      self.name = name

if __name__ == '__main__':
   jimmy = Patient('Jimmy')
   Patient.say = say
   jimmy.say('Hello')
```

yields

```
Jimmy says Hello
```

---

If you did want to attach a staticmethod, then, as MartijnPieters answered, use the `staticmethod` decorator:

```
def tell(msg):
   print(msg)

if __name__ == '__main__':
   jimmy = Patient('Jimmy')
   Patient.tell = staticmethod(tell)
   jimmy.tell('Goodbye')
```

yields

```
Goodbye
```

---

The above shows how new methods can be attached to a class without `funcToMethod` or `transplant`. Both `funcToMethod` and `transplant` try to attach functions to *instances* of the class rather than the class itself. This is wrong-headed, which is why it requires contortions (like having to pass `jimmy` as an argument in `jimmy.say2(jimmy, 'Good Bye!')`) to make it work. Methods should be defined on the class (e.g. `Patient`), not on the instance (e.g. `jimmy`).

`transplant` is particularly horrible. It uses a class when a function would suffice. It uses the archaic `apply` instead of the modern `self.method(*nargs, **kwargs)` syntax, and ignores the PEP8 convention for camelCasing class names. In its defense, it was written over ten years ago. But fundamentally, what makes it an anathema to good programming is that you just don't need it.

Answer (score 0):

Well the following works, ie puts a static method on Patient which I think the OP was wanting.

```
def tell(msg):
   print(msg)

...

funcToMethod(tell, Patient, 'say3')

...

Patient.say3('Bye!')
```